# Find out which Grails nested field fails to serialize

Tags: grails, serialization, groovy, spymemcached

I'm trying to serialize a Grails domain class instance into Memcached just after updating the domain instance by normal data binding.

When I'm doing this, I'm getting `NotSerializableException` saying `Caused by NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject` which looks like one of the field inside the domain instance is not serializable which is not implementing Serializable interface which is of type `JSONObject` of Groovy.

But, my domain class does not having such a field. This clearly states that some thing is being set by Grails databinding, since this serialization is working fine if I freshly get a instance.

So, is there any way of knowing that which field is actually failed to serialize?